# What's ignoring the gradle wrapper?

Tags: git, sourcetree

## The setup

New intellij install, new sourcetree installation, new android project, `.gitignore` has been initialized as:

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
```

## The problem

The files in the gradle wrapper, that's `gradle/wrapper/gradle.properties` and `gradle/wrapper/gradle.jar` are ignored. And they [should be added](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:wrapper_generation).

```
$git add gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar 
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
```

It does not tell me which `.gitignore` file.

There is no `.gitignore` in `gradle/` or `gradle/wrapper`.

While I can force this, I don't want to forget in future projects.

Comment: Can you do a `grep` for the string `gradle` in any file named `.gitignore`, starting at the root of your project?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `$grep -r "gradle" .gitignore` gives just `.gitignore:/.gradle`

Comment: Did you run this from the very top of the project?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes

Comment: Have you looked under your home directory ($HOME/.config/git/ignore)? The ignore files can live in a few different places. See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore for a list of them.

Comment: Also, did you check for `gradle/` and `gradle/wrapper/` folders to make sure there isn't a `.gitignore` there?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It sounds like a global ignore file is what’s gumming up the works here. You can use `git check-ignore --verbose gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` to see exactly what pattern from which file is determining git’s ignore behavior. ([Docs on `git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore))

I think the best real solution here to make sure that this particular file is not ignored, irregardless of global ignore files or broad rules for ignoring `.jar` files.

To that end, you can add `!/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` to the end of your repo’s `.gitignore` file. (See the finer points of `.gitignore` file pattern matching & exclusion at bottom of the [docs on `.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore))

Comment: The excluding line was just `gradle`. I found I could only re-include the files if I added `!gradle` Would you expect that?

Comment: @weston `!gradle` at some point in the file, should re-include any file named `gradle` that was previously excluded by a previous rule in the file.

However, in this case, an “ignore” pattern followed by the same explicit “do not ignore” pattern does not make much sense to me. Presumably a broad “ignore” pattern is there for a reason, and anything that is an exception that to that broad pattern should be expressed with a more narrow pattern.

E.g., with my answer’s example: ignore `*.jar` generally, but explicitly do _not_ ignore this `.jar`, at this path, in this project.

Comment: Yeah I agree, but couldn't get `!/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` in the project's local `.gitignore` to work, only `!gradle`.

Comment: Weird. I’ve never gotten quite clear on whether or not you have to commit changes to a `.gitignore` repo before its new rules will be honored, or if it being modified and/or staged is enough. Maybe your trouble had something to do with that?

Comment: Well it respects `!gradle` immediately. It is weird, I will investigate further sometime.